# ServiceStack webservice broken after installing ServiceStack.Logging.Log4Net

Tags: servicestack

A working web service is broken after installing ServiceStack.Logging.Log4Net with package-manager (in VS Express 2012 Web)

The exception thrown on initializing is:
Method 'Add' in type 'ServiceStack.ServiceHost.ServiceRoutes' from assembly 'ServiceStack, Version=3.9.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.

This happened after installing logging in two different applications. (I deliberately tried breaking the second one by installing logging, just to be sure, and it did break...)
Cleaning and rebuilding the whole thing makes doesn't fix this.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

We've just re-deployed all the latest (v1.04) logging libraries for ServiceStack.Logging which now should be in-sync with the latest version of ServiceStack.Common libraries.

Comment: oke, uninstalling and re-installing all my servicestack packages fixed the issue. was i naive to think that installing a new package automagically resolves all dependencies on previously installed packages?

Comment: You have to explicitly update all NuGet packages you want to update.